# Ansible role and playbook organization for multiple products/teams

Tags: git, ansible, organization

We started with ansible using the ansible best practices [text](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html), but now it is becoming unmanageable. For this reason, we are trying to re-organize our ansible structure and to divide it in multiple git repositories.

Our use case is that we have a very complex system, where there are several teams developing solutions in dedicated testing environments, where every solution includes several applications,databases, etc. Until now, everybody was using a single git repo with a single "role" and "playbook" folders. Our structure looks like this:

```
- group_vars
- host_vars
- inventory
- roles
   - team1_role
       - tasks
            - sqlite.yml
            - app1_1.yml 
            - app1_2.yml 
   - team2_role
       - tasks
            - sqlite.yml
            - app2_1.yml
            - app2_2.yml
   - team3_role
   -...
- playbooks
   - team1_playbook
       - team1.yml --> where this playbook install sqlite in host1, app1_1 and app1_2 in host2
       - team1_action1.yml --> where this playbook perform some maintenance activity, such as update passwords. 
   - team2_role
       - team2.yml --> where this playbook install sqlite in host3, app2_1 and app2_2 in host2
   - all.yml
```

After reading several webs, I see straight forward that we have to create a repository per "team_role" and a "common_role" with common things such as the sqlite.yml. For us, creating a repository per app would not have any benefit.

But, we dont know what to do with the playbooks. I only see tree options:

- Create a second repository per team with the playbooks
- Allow the teams to access and edit a central ansible repository with all the playbooks.
- Create a single repository per team with playbooks and roles a change the ansible structure to something like this:

```
- team1
    - roles
    - playbooks
- team1
    - roles
    - playbooks
```

What would you recomend after your experience?

## Solution

We finally agreed to do it using the third option. It is not the ansible best practice, but the solution of defining a colection per role does not seem to work in short term for us. Let's see if the experience does not show us that we are wrong.

Then, we are defining a single repository per team where they will write their roles and playbooks. Then we will have a repository for the common inventory (probably shared for all the teams) and a repository for common roles (in long term we migh change this to have a repository per role).

So, the final structure will be:

```
 - group_vars
 - host_vars
 - inventory
 - common_roles
    - sqlite.yml
 - teams
    - team1
       - roles
            - app1_1.yml 
            - app1_2.yml 
       - playbooks
            - team1.yml
    - team2
       - roles
            - app2_1.yml
            - app2_2.yml
       - playbooks
            - team2.yml
    - team3
       -...
```

Answer (score 1):

You might benefit from using [Ansible Collections](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections_guide/index.html)

And detach roles from playbooks in two repositories. You would have:

- Ansible Collections repository, hosting reusable roles across different teams
- Ansible playbooks repository for each team, making use of the roles defined in the Ansible Collections repository

Everything that can be reused across more than one team and/or application, goes to the Ansible Collections repository. Everything else is stored in the repository of each team/application.

Structure of the Ansible Collections repository could be as follows:

```
ansible-collection/
└── myorg
    ├── database
    │   └── roles
    │       ├── mysql
    │       ├── postgresql
    │       └── sqlite
    ├── team1
    │   └── roles
    │       ├── appA
    │       └── appB
    └── team2
        └── roles
            ├── appC
            └── appD
```

And you make use of the roles in a playbook:

```
---
- hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: myorg.database.sqlite
    - include_role:
        name: myorg.team1.appA
```

This keeps your code DRY and empowers your organization to reuse existing code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But then, the idea would be that all teams modify a single collection in a git repository? Or it would work more like some artifacts in the galaxy library?

Comment: Yes, or you can have a separate collection for each team and then one collection for the common roles. Just put all the reusable code in collections ;)

Comment: I've being reading a little more about collections. I see in a collection it is possilbe to include roles and playbooks. What do you think if each team send us a collection with their roles and their playbooks? This way, the teams could have a single ansible repository with their collection, which does their full deployment.